# Eclipse Juno CDT, linking a specific .so

Tags: eclipse, shared-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I can't find a proper way to link a specific .so with Eclipse CDT: I need to link on Ubuntu thinks like libGL.so.1.2.0, and in the CDT project I have to omit the prefix 'lib' and the suffix '.so'.

How can I specify that kind of things?

Answer (score 0):

There will probably be a libGL.so symbolic link somewhere, so using -lGL should do it.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I've multiple versions of the same library installed, and different projects are referring to different versions. So I was wondering if was possible to do everything inside CDT, to avoid cluttering the projects directories with a bunch of symbolic links.